# Angular JS: How do i call a second service from controller and update the DOM with returned Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Service that gets called initially when the page loads and based on the result my custom directive gets constructed, when the DOM is constructed i want to call one more service to which some data from first result should be passed and based on this result i want to update the already constructed DOM. For Example Student data gets constructed and then new service is called to passing student Id to get Attendance status, and based on the data received i want to show Green or Red image (which is already in the DOM but need to show/hide it).

1. What is the right way to do it ?
2. Result of Second service is an json object, how do i add class based on ID ?

**First Directive**

```html
<div ng-controller="studentCtrl">
  <div ng-if="showTable">
    <student-view></student-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller.js**

```js
angular.module('adf.widget.student')
  .controller('studentCtrl', ['$scope', 'students',
    function($scope, students) {
      //students is service.
      var data = students;
      var key;
      $scope.ids = [];
      if (data.students.length > 0) {
        $scope.students = data.students;
        for (key in $scope.students) {
          if ($scope.students[key]['id'] !== '') {
            $scope.ids.push($scope.students[key]['id']);
          }
        }
        $scope.showTable = true;
      } else {
        $scope.showTable = false;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

**Directive.js**

```js
angular.module('adf.widget.student')
  .directive('studentView', function(dashboard) {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'studentView.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'studentViewDirectiveCtrl'
    }
  })
```

**studentViewDirectiveCtrl.js**

```js
angular.module('adf.widget.student')
  .controller('studentViewDirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', 'secondService',
    function($scope, secondService) {

      secondService.getStatus($scope.ids)
        .then(function(result) {
          $scope.status = result.status;
        })
        .catch(function() {
          /* error :( */
        });

    }
  ]);
```

**studentViewTemplate.html**

```html
<div ng-repeat="std in students" class="student">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="../rv/{{std .image}}" />

  <div class="showLed">
    <!-- How do i add red/green className based on the Second Service Result -->
    <div class="led" style="position:absolute" class="red/green">
    </div>
  </div>
  ....
```

Result of Second Service

```
{
    "status": [{
        "id": 1,
        "stat": "true"
    }, {
         "id": 2,
        "stat": "false"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "stat": "false"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "stat": "true"
    }]
}
```

Comment: use `ng-class` diretive for this

Comment: Is the `id` in status array is student `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following;

```
<div class="led"
     style="position:absolute"
     ng-class="{ 'green': status[std.id], 'red': !status[std.id] }">
```

You should update your studentViewDirectiveCtrl with the following;

```
angular.module('adf.widget.student')
  .controller('studentViewDirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', 'secondService',
    function($scope, secondService) {
      function organiseStatus(status) {
        var returnMap = {};
        for (index in status) {
          var statu = status[index];
          returnMap[statu.id] = statu.stat == 'true' ? true : false;
        }

        return returnMap;
      }

      secondService.getStatus($scope.ids)
        .then(function(result) {
          $scope.status = organiseStatus(result.status);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            /* error :( */
        });
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: But returned result is an array of object which contains status of students that i passed.

Comment: If these status are ordered by student array, you can check with $index. I have updated my answer.

Comment: {
    "status": [{
        "id": 1,
        "stat": "true"
    }, {
         "id": 2,
        "stat": "false"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "stat": "false"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "stat": "true"
    }]
} //this is my result

Comment: @SharathBangera I have updated my answer again. You can check my answer again.

Comment: Can you please tell me what $index in status[$index]. its adding "Red" class for everything.

Comment: This is index of each rows/items of array. $index will be 0 for first row, 1 for second row etc. Do you share your $scope.student object too? Now, I will update my answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114964/discussion-between-ali-barin-and-sharath-bangera).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` directive and check for the return value of a functional expression to apply the red or green class.

**studentViewTemplate.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="std in students" class="student">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="../rv/{{std .image}}" />

  <div class="showLed">
    <!-- How do i add red/green className based on the Second Service Result -->
    <div class="led" style="position:absolute" ng-class="isStatusTrue(std.id) ? 'green' : 'red'">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
```

**studentViewDirectiveCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('adf.widget.student')
  .controller('studentViewDirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', 'secondService', '$filter',
    function($scope, secondService, $filter) {
        secondService.getStatus($scope.ids)
           .then(function(result) {
                $scope.status = result.status;
            },
            function() {
                /* error */
            }
        );

        // method to check student status
        $scope.isStatusTrue = function(studentID) {
            $scope.studentStatus = $filter('filter')($scope.students, {id: studentID})[0];
            if($scope.studentStatus && $scope.studentStatus.stat == "true") {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
]);
```

Here, `isStatusTrue` function will check if status is true or not for a student. Based on that corresponding class will be shown in the template using the `ng-class` directive.